# how to group by id and show partial totals?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is basic but i havent been able to crack it.
I have the following dataset:

```
df222 = structure(list(D_NoIDProv = c("900341526", "900580962", "900098550", 
"900098550", "900098550", "900098550", "900098550", "900098550", 
"900098550", "900098550"), D_TipoTec = c("M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), CUMS = c("222", "20086945-03", 
"19971860-01", "20024899-02", "20060305-01", "222", "20086945-03", 
"20024861-01", "20025390-12", "222"), D_CantTotAEntregar = c(7, 
60, 2, 300, 1, 120, 60, 30, 30, 30), D_FecDireccionamiento = structure(c(1579002420, 
1579119060, 1580119920, 1580231220, 1580231400, 1580231520, 1580231700, 
1580231760, 1580317860, 1580317920), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), D_FecMaxEnt = structure(c(18276, 18308, 18286, 18291, 
18282, 18272, 18271, 18271, 18282, 18342), class = "Date"), ValorUnitarioMax = c(159010, 
4458, 1481574, 3261, 2071490, 481, 3437, 628, 4087, 4087), ValorTotal = c(1113070, 
267480, 2963148, 978300, 2071490, 57720, 206220, 18840, 122610, 
122610)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

im trying

```
df222 %>%  group_by("CUMS") %>% 
  summarise(MainTotal= sum(ValorTotal))
```

but all i get in an unique total

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `group_by(CUMS)`, no quote marks

Comment: thanks so much. im just too tired and missed that simple thing

Answer (score 3):

We can use

```
df222 %>%
   group_by(across("CUMS")) %>%
   summarise(MainTotal = sum(ValorTotal))
```